# NSDictionary parsing Exception in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am using this code and it is giving exception

```
    NSMutableArray *streams = (NSMutableArray *)[feed valueForKey:@"comments"];
    NSMutableArray *streams1 = (NSMutableArray *)[streams valueForKey:@"data"];
    //NSMutableArray *streams2 = (NSMutableArray *)[streams1 valueForKey:@"message"];
    // loop over all the stream objects and print their titles
    int index;
    NSMutableDictionary *stream;
  for (index = 0; index < [feed count];index++) {
        stream = (NSMutableDictionary *)[streams1 objectAtIndex:index];

                NSLog(@"Name of sender is: %@", [stream valueForKey:@"message"]); 

        }


FaceBookTable *detailViewController = [[FaceBookTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"FaceBookTable" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    detailViewController.fbGraph = fbGraph;
    detailViewController.dummyArray  = [ feed valueForKey:@"message"];
    detailViewController.dict = stream;

}
```

Exception is

```
-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5dae960
2011-06-15 16:14:07.835 MultiSocial[8042:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5dae960'
```

while my other code is working fine

```
    NSMutableArray *streams = (NSMutableArray *)[feed valueForKey:@"from"];
    lueForKey:@"message"];
    // loop over all the stream objects and print their titles
    int index;
    NSMutableDictionary *stream;
for (index = 0; index < [feed count];index++) {
        stream = (NSMutableDictionary *)[streams objectAtIndex:index];

                NSLog(@"Name of sender is: %@", [stream valueForKey:@"message"]); 



    }
```

Please help

here is crash log

```
2011-06-15 17:05:42.148 MultiSocial[8583:207] -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d05f50
2011-06-15 17:05:42.156 MultiSocial[8583:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d05f50'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x013cabe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0151f5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x013cc6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0133c366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0133bf22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x00649405 -[UITableViewLabel setText:] + 84
    6   MultiSocial                         0x00046147 -[FaceBookTable tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 467
    7   UIKit                               0x0045f7fa -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 634
    8   UIKit                               0x0045577f -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x0046a450 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
    10  UIKit                               0x00462538 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
    11  QuartzCore                          0x01e98451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01e9817c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01e9137c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    14  QuartzCore                          0x01e910d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    15  QuartzCore                          0x01ec17d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x013abfbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x013410e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01309bd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01309240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01309161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0190f268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0190f32d GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x003fa42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  MultiSocial                         0x00002740 main + 102
    25  MultiSocial                         0x000026d1 start + 53
)
```

Comment: It’d help if you edited your question and posted both the JSON data you’re parsing and the code you’re using to parse them.

Comment: The exception log says the exception is happening in `-[FaceBookTable tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`, please post the complete method (if it isn't too long). Also, you shouldn't use `valueForKey:` when accessing a dictionary but `objectForKey:` (the former is used for KVC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as per the crash log -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:] there is some mistake in your code. It is clearly visible in the crash report that isEqualToString method is for NSString object but in your code it is called on NSArray.

Just debug your app and you will find the solution.

**UPDATE**

```
//Make sure that feed return an array for the key comments
 NSArray *streams = (NSArray *)[feed valueForKey:@"comments"];
 NSArray *streams1 = (NSArray *)[streams valueForKey:@"data"];

 NSLog(@"comments : %@",streams);

//When you are running loop only last index value will be copied into your dictionary named stream so remove the loop.

FaceBookTable *detailViewController = [[FaceBookTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"FaceBookTable" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    detailViewController.fbGraph = fbGraph;
    detailViewController.dummyArray  = [ feed valueForKey:@"message"];
    detailViewController.dict = streams;

}
```

//Your tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method should look like this

```
//First get the dictionary

if(dict){
        NSDictionary *stream = (NSDictionary *)[dict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       if(stream){
            NSDictionary * messages = (NSDictionary *[stream valueForKey:@"Message"];

            NSString *comment = [messages valueForKey:@"comment"];

           cell.textLabel.text = comment;
       }
}
```

Comment: detailViewController.dict = stream; this line is reason of crash but this is working fine for single Array.please help

Comment: @Pallavi you are assigning a mutable array to a dictionary

Comment: comments =         {
            count = 1;
            data =             (
                                {
                    "created_time" = "2011-06-14T13:04:13+0000";
                    from =                     {
                        id = 100001507678574;
                        name = "Widevision Dev";
                    };
                    id = "100001507678574_173242299402691_1823114";
                    message = "Comment on selected post";
                }
            );
        }; Trying to show message= "".. It displaying on console but giving exceptionindictionary

Comment: @Pallavi You don't need to use NSMutableArray instead you can use NSArray. Also debug your app and see what this line return an array or a dictionary "[streams valueForKey:@"data"];"

Comment: passing mutablearray is working but when I use more than one array ,It is giving error.. dict and stream both are Nsdictionary

Comment: It seems json data use json kit to parse this json and create a dictionary using the json data.

Comment: This is the output of json..I am trying to get facebook comments of each post.And able to get it on console. Just having problem in showing it on next viewcontroller in Uitableview

Comment: NSString *commentId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[feed valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"data" ]valueForKey:@"id"]]; NSLog(@"Comment Id is %@:",commentId); If I pass NSString then How can I view this commentsid in tableview?

Comment: Comment Id is ( ( "100001507678574_173436826049905_1826918", "100001507678574_173436826049905_1826933" ),

Comment: Why don't you create a data modal for comments? give dictionary to datamodal and data modal is prepared. Add datamodal to array and finally pass that array to your tableViewController's array

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"message"] ;  This is giving exception

Comment: @Pallavi debug and check what is this line returning [dict valueForKey:@"message"]  or directly print the contents of dict

Comment: It is returning 2 objects and then signal received SIGABART

Comment: @Pallavi could you please post the log here

Comment: @Pallavi please post the contents of [dict valueForKey:@"message"] the dict you are using in the method.

Comment: Message  is  :(
    hmmmmm,
    yupiee
)
2011-06-15 17:18:18.347 MultiSocial[8860:207]  Message  is  :(
    hmmmmm,
    yupiee
)
2011-06-15 17:18:18.347 MultiSocial[8860:207]  Message  is  :(
    hmmmmm,
    yupiee
)

Comment: That's why you are getting crash your dict contains nothing it is nil actually first you need to check if the dict has the object for the key message then further you need to get string out from the dictionary by specifying a key for that string and then if string!= nil assign the string to cell.textlabel.text

Comment: ok..and I am thinking NSLog is printing dict value..and might be problem in cell.textlabel.text=[dict objectforkey:@"message"] cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; because I am returning row : return [dummyarray count];

Comment: hmmm..might be..If I have any problem I will tell you. thanks for the help

Comment: @Pallavi welcom. Happy coding:-). Just an advice for you always try to debug your app before asking the question on stackoverflow it will increase your efficiency,logical power and so many things. It' a real fact.

Comment: ya thats true..but still my problem is not solved...I would try to solve :)

Comment: I have created model class for facebook json data..It is working fine..but I am having problem in getting comments..- (id)initWithFacebookDictionary:(NSDictionary *)_facebook {


 if (self = [super init]) {
  facebook = _facebook;
  [facebook retain];
  
 }
 return self;


}
- (NSString *)post {

 return [[[facebook objectForKey:@"comments"] objectForKey:@"data"]  objectForKey:@"message"];

}

Comment: It is ok with return[[facebook objectForKey:@"comments"]objectForkey:@"data"];

Comment: @Pallavi It is a bad practice to write this kind of code and also troublesome to debug [[[facebook objectForKey:@"comments"] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"message"]; please make each line seperate so that your code is easier to read and easier to manage. Put comments wherever needed. But I am still unable to get your question.

Comment: @Pallavi I'm sending you a example data model class in mail so that you can learn how to parse nsdictionary and create a data modal.

Comment: No but you can print the output dictionary and prepare your datamodal as the output.

Comment: hmm checked your mail..trying to understand that

Comment: hey I am able to get comments of particular post

Answer (score 0):

u have been assigning the NSString object to NSArray.so do debug with breakpoints

Comment: I checked it with breakpoints ..It is throwing exception on detailViewController.dict = stream;

Comment: NSString *commentId = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[feed valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"data" ]valueForKey:@"id"]];
NSLog(@"Comment Id is %@:",commentId);  If I pass NSString then How can I view this commentsid in tableview?

Comment: Comment Id is (
        (
        "100001507678574_173436826049905_1826918",
        "100001507678574_173436826049905_1826933"
    ),

Comment: check ur dict is NSString or NSDIc in detailViewController

Comment: It is NSDicionary ..Working fine for  NSMutableArray *streams = (NSMutableArray *)[feed valueForKey:@"from"];for (index = 0; index < [feed count];index++) {
        stream = (NSMutableDictionary *)[streams objectAtIndex:index];

But not more more than one array

Comment: NSMutableArray *arr=[[[feed valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"data" ]valueForKey:@"id"];

  for (NSString* cid in arr) {
   
   
   NSLog(@"cid is : %@ \n\n",cid);
   
   
  }

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"message"] ; This is giving exception

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[[feed valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"data" ]valueForKey:@"id"];
for (NSString* cid in [arr objectAtIndex:0]) {
    NSLog(@"cid is : %@ \n\n",cid);
}
```

Comment: if u have more doubt go to Iphone/ipad chat room

Comment: ok..How can I pass this to next view.. using like  this detailViewController.nameArray = [[[feed valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"data" ]valueForKey:@"message"]; giving exception